# Bezier curve not properly modifying a mesh

Tags: bezier-curves

Does anyone know why this cube mesh is not following the Bezier curve? I made sure to set the origins at both their respective ends and I have enough vertices for it. I also tried every deformation axis. I would very much appreciate some help, as I've been stuck with this for a while. Thanks[image]

Comment: It appears so, at least. Here is an illustration of how the subdivisions look: https://i.imgur.com/IIiAeZj.png

Comment: Ahh, sorry, looking at the wrong bit. First shot: try Ctrl-A applying the scale of both the curve and deformed object.

Comment: Tried that–no change unfortunately